# How to fetch data from S3 to Dataframe in Pyspark (Jupyter) quicker?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, memory-efficient

Currently with default pyspark ( jupyter ) configurations, the s3 data( about 20 gb Parquet files) take 2.5 hours to read into a dataframe.

However, When I changed the driver memory and executor memory to 7g strangely the task of read keeps failing with exception printed below. Did not modify anything in the code.

1. What is causing the timeout?
2. How else to make the DF read faster? It is not feasible to wait 2.5 hours to load data into a dataframe.

Code :

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    import pandas

    # SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages","org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.0.0-alpha3")
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", 'A')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", 's')

    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    print(sc._conf.getAll())
    df = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3n://sm/data/scor/alpha/2016/parquet/part-*.parquet")
    df.count()
```

Error :

```
<pre> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 362, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
```

Pyspark instance started using :

```
     pyspark --jars "/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-aws-3.0.0-alpha3.jar,/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.11.150.jar,/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.150.jar,/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.150.jar,/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/httpcore-4.4.6.jar,/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/httpclient-4.5.3.jar" --driver-memory 7g --executor-memory 7g
```

Comment: When I run it again it fails with : SSL socket exception

Comment: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 726, localhost, executor driver): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake

Comment: 2.5 hrs to download 20GiB worth of parquet files gives about 2.3MiB/s transfer rate. Are you running this jupyter on a small instance with low bandwidth capacity? I presume you are not using a full cluster but rather are using the local spark deploy mode. Is it feasible to 1) get larger instance(s), 2) download the files one time, 3) use only certain columns (thus not needing the whole files), 4) spin up an emr cluster and use zeppelin built into it or manually provision Livy and spark magic in jupyter to submit jobs via Livy to your larger cluster?

Comment: Yea I am using a local standalone instance. About Larger instance - not currently until code is complete. 2. Can be done ( downloading 1 time). 3. I need to load whole data and change all column values 1 by 1. 4. Im not sure what to follow for this

Comment: What instance type are you using? Try oversubscribing your CPUs by setting `--master local[n]` where n is the number of local cores (such as 2) * 2 or 4. If your instance type is something small like t2.small, there may not be any good solution to your problem that lets you only use your existing resources. Do you need help with code to be sure what you're trying to do is optimal/needed?

Comment: This is a local machine with 12 gig RAM and around 200 gb space. Cores are 2. Do you need help with code to be sure what you're trying to do is optimal/needed? - Yes. please

Comment: Local machine means not on AWS. If that's the case, then it also explains why transfer rate (~2.3MiB/s) is so low. If your ISP is the limiting factor, then no amount of code would change the ultimate calculus of transfer speed. I suggest opening a new question to ask for help with your specific code issue (what columns you're changing, why, etc). Otherwise, download the files one time and just keep them locally.